# Pointer at 0th index problematic

Tags: pointers, fortran

```
module shared
!derived type target here
integer, parameter :: nblock = 2
integer, parameter :: xdim   = 2

TYPE block_info
    INTEGER                               :: il=10,jl=20,kl=30
    REAL, ALLOCATABLE                     :: x(:)
END TYPE block_info
TYPE(block_info), TARGET :: block(nblock)

end module shared


module point_to
!point to subroutine here
use shared

REAL, POINTER :: x(:)
integer       :: il,jl,kl

contains

subroutine set_current(n)
    nullify(x)
    il = block(n)%il
    jl = block(n)%jl
    kl = block(n)%kl
    x => block(n)%x(0:xdim)
end subroutine set_current

end module point_to


program main

use shared
use point_to

!Iam allocating derived type target and initialize
do i = 1, nblock
    allocate(block(i)%x(0:xdim))
    do j = 0, xdim
        block(i)%x(j) = dble(i)*dble(j)
    enddo
enddo

!Iam pointing using set_current subroutine and print
do i = 1, nblock
    call set_current(i)
    do j = 0, xdim
        write(*,*) "i= ",i, "j= ",j, block(i)%x(j), x(j)
    enddo
enddo


end program main
```

For the above code I'am getting the following output;

```
 i=            1 j=            0   0.00000000       0.00000000    
 i=            1 j=            1   1.00000000       0.00000000    
 i=            1 j=            2   2.00000000       1.00000000    
 i=            2 j=            0   0.00000000       0.00000000    
 i=            2 j=            1   2.00000000       0.00000000    
 i=            2 j=            2   4.00000000       2.00000000
```

I have applied the x vector starting from 1 to xdim and I got no error. When first index is chosen as 0 the problems start. In above output last two values must be equal. So where is the problem?

Comment: You used tag [tag:fortran90]. Always use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. You can add another tag to distinguish a version. *However*, your code is NOT Fortran 90. Allocatable components to derived types are not even allowed in original Fortran 95, it is a Fortran 2003 feature. So your code is Fortran 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vladimir F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370589) explains the origin of the problem.  However, that detail is something that comes up very frequently in questions here, so it's worth stressing a couple of things.

An array section, even when it matches all the elements of an array, is not the same thing as the whole array.  `block(n)%x` is a whole array; `block(n)%x(0:xdim)` is an array section (even when that array component has bounds `0` and `xdim`).

Why does this difference matter?  Let's look at the rules of pointer assignment.  The pointer assignment statement

```
x => block(n)%x(0:xdim)
```

is one of data pointer assignment.  As that other answer mentions, there is such a thing as *bounds remapping*.  It's also possible to give a bounds specification.

Neither of those two cases are happening here, and I'll come onto that more later, so we're in the case of (see Fortran 2008, 7.2.2.3)

> If *bounds-spec-list* appears, it specifies the lower bounds; otherwise, the lower bound of each dimension is the result of the intrinsic function LBOUND (13.7.90) applied to the corresponding dimension of the pointer target.

The result of `LBOUND` is where the whole array/array section distinction is important (Fortran 2008, 13.7.90):

> If ARRAY is a whole array ... LBOUND (ARRAY, DIM) has a value equal to the lower bound for subscript DIM of ARRAY.  Otherwise the result value is 1.

This means that `LBOUND(block(n)%x)` has result `0` in this case, but `LBOUND(block(n)%x(0:xdim))` has result `1` always.

Which all means

```
x => block(n)%x  ! x has lower bound 0
x => block(n)%x(0:xdim)  ! x has lower bound 1
```

Now, Vladimir F mentions bounds remapping:

```
x(0:xdim) => block(n)%x(0:xdim)
```

This says that `x` has the requested upper and lower bounds.  This is quite legitimate, but comes with a couple of warnings:

- one has to be careful repeating the bounds; the left-hand size must have at most the same number of elements as the right-hand size, and if fewer then it's a smaller array.
- the right-hand side must be either rank-1 or simply contiguous.

All of those conditions hold, but this makes generalization require care.

Finally, then, there is a bounds specification:

```
x(0:) => block(n)%x(0:xdim)
```

This still specifies the lower bound, but the pointer and the target always have the same size and there's no restriction on rank/contiguity.

To conclude: use `x => block(n)%x` for the simple situation of this question.

Comment: Such a great explanation thank you sir, now it is all clear

Answer (score 1):

First, when you have a problem, use all the debugging features your compiler has, just looking at the code is not enough.

For example:

```
> gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall zeroptr.f90 
zeroptr.f90:44.24:

        block(i)%x(j) = dble(i)*dble(j)
                        1
Warning: Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to REAL(4) at (1)
> ./a.out 
At line 52 of file zeroptr.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '0' of dimension 1 of array 'x' below lower bound of 1

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7fa2d4af3607 in ???
#1  0x7fa2d4af4115 in ???
#2  0x7fa2d4af44ba in ???
#3  0x4014dc in MAIN__
        at /home/lada/f/testy/stackoverflow/zeroptr.f90:52
#4  0x401640 in main
        at /home/lada/f/testy/stackoverflow/zeroptr.f90:37
```

The compiler tells you directly where the error is. The array `x` starts at element `1` and you are trying to access element `0` so you are out of bounds. It happens at line 52 which is

```
   write(*,*) "i= ",i, "j= ",j, block(i)%x(j), x(j)
```

Why is it so? Because

```
  x => block(n)%x(0:xdim)
```

makes `x` pointing to `block(n)%x(0:xdim)`, but `x` will start at 1!

In Fortran 2003 you can do this (pointer remapping):

```
 x(0:xdim) => block(n)%x(0:xdim)
```

and it works as expected, but better just use `block(n)%x`.

Comment: Setting  x(0:xdim) => block(n)%x(0:xdim) solved my problem. thank you so much.

Comment: By the way I'm using GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4 version but the debug options are not working as you said, there is no error given. How this can be occur? Thank you again.

Comment: My version is 4.8.5 so it should work as I have shown. The error is shown when you run the code compiled for debugging!